# Cant find Token in Local or Session Storage from a webapplication using chrome-dev-tool. Is there any other way its stored, maybe in a encrypted?

Tags: request, google-chrome-devtools, token, tokenize

So I tried to debug "https://www.ea.com/de-de/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/" a simple web-application.

I log in and after that it sends **requests with a token**(here its called "**X-UT-SID**"). The thing is I cant find the **token** in any storage using chrome developers-tool. Is there any other way a token is stored like maybe encrypted in the cookie?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can run "window.localStorage" on console. Then, you can trace back the auth requests with these session data